# Count how many times a string starts with another substring

Tags: python, string, list

Trying to figure out out many times string beings with certain string.

If user inputs a number of strings I want to return number of times it begins with "foo". I want the program to end if user types empty space ""

```
   foohi
   nothingfoo
   fooboo
   example
```

the answer equals 2

I have started my attempt but do not know where to go from here

```
answer = []
print("please enter string: ", end="")
s = input()
```

Comment: Well, there's a built-in method called `startswith` you can use; if you have a list of strings, you could iterate over them - have a go first. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=startswith#str.startswith

Comment: can you give an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's built-in `split` to split the string into a list of words and  `startswith` method to find the words that starts with `foo`.

```py
def count_foo() -> int:

    while True:      
        print("please enter string: ")
        s = input().strip()

        if s == "":
            break

        else:
            # counter
            answer = 0

            # split the string to make a list of individual words
            words = s.split()

            # iterate through the list and find words 
            # that starts with foo
            for word in words:
                if word.startswith('foo'):
                    answer += 1

            print(answer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    answer = count_foo()
```

Now when the prompt pops up, add your string:

```
foohi nothingfoo fooboo example
```

This will print:

```py
2
```

If you just hit `enter` without putting anything in the input prompt, it will get out of the loop.

Comment: I want the user to insert as many as wanted then end the program with an empty string

Comment: sorry. i want the user to type each time a different new string not a list of string. For example, reads a series of string one by one

Comment: Updated my answer and let me know if that satiates your case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to set the EOF to `\n`, but if you hit `CTRL-D`, reading from `stdin` will stop:

```
>>> import sys
>>> i = sys.stdin.readlines()
foohi
nothingfoo
fooboo
example
>>>
```

Number of strings beginning with `foo`:

```
>>> sum(s.startswith("foo") for s in i)
2
```

Comment: The most pythonic and concise answer

Answer (score 0):

You below code:

```
ls= ['foohi',
'nothingfoo',
'fooboo',
'example']
i=0
print("please enter string: ", end="")
s = input()
for l in ls:
    if l.startswith(s):
        i=i+1
print(i)
```

Comment: I'd refrain from using built-in functions as variable names; namely `list`.

Comment: I don't want a list at the start. I want the user to insert as many as wanted then end the program with an empty string